# Wget with brackets [] in url

Tags: wget

I must call a url in a cronjob, but wget excludes the second parameter from the url.
url format:

```
https://example.com/frontend/?ml[do]=doStuff&ml[auth]=someAuthCode
```

Wget excludes the second parameter, so i become "access denied"

i tried too:

```
https://example.com/frontend/?ml\[do\]=doStuff&ml\[auth\]=someAuthCode
```

-d confirms the removal

```
---request begin---
GET /frontend/?ml[do]=doStuffHTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
---request end---
```

How can i call the correct url with 2 get variables includes brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is acting on the `&`, which ends a command; you need to escape that too (as well as `?` which like `[...]` is a globbing operator):

```
wget https://example.com/frontend/\?ml\[do\]=doStuff\&ml\[auth\]=someAuthCode
```

or

```
wget 'https://example.com/frontend/?ml[do]=doStuff&ml[auth]=someAuthCode'
```

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440)